# Asp.Net web application publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I developed an `ASP.NET` `MVC 4` application that uses an `Entity Framework Code First` database and I published it in Internet information Services (`ISS`) using the web deploy package method. The website runs perfect till I try to access to a view that makes use of the database, it gives me the following error:

> Detalles de la excepción: System.ArgumentException: El formato de la cadena de inicialización no se ajusta a la especificación que comienza en el índice 0.

This is happening when I try to acces to the website after being published in `ISS`, however when I run it from `VisualStudio` it works perfectly. I wonder if I have to change anything in the `web.config` file after publishing the application. I would be thankful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to update your connection strings! The section in your web.config that tells the application what data source to connect to. Make sure you have your SQL server running and you have the correct connection strings in your web.config.

Comment: i didn't use sql server, instead i created a model and CodeFirst Generated a database file based on it, the value of my connectionString is: <add name="SocialNetworkDb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SocialNetworkDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SocialNetworkDb_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SocialNetworkDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />